# HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Although my code compiles and runs I am plagued by little red squiggly lines.  For example, Html.BeginForm is not recognised.  Although, if I type "Html." then intellisense does suggest some other methods such as Checkbox and DropDownList.

Other underlines include model and ViewBag.

I've got a reference to MVC 5.2.3.0 and the System.Web.Mvc namespace is in my web.config

This has been going on for months and is wasting a lot of my time.  I'm sure it has something to do with the versions of packages I have installed but I don't understand it enough to be able to troubleshoot it.

I've rebuilt my computer, reinstalled Visual Studio 2013, and copied my code back (in chunks to try to isolate the problem) but I'm getting nowhere fast.

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this before I switch careers?

Answer (score 5):

make sure you have both, the controller and action method name in the BeginForm Method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ActionmethodName, ControllerName, FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly like is your config problem. Make sure your **Views** folder's t **web.config** have config like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SixAnts" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

using the version of your packges and your namespace

Comment: <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

Comment: Thanks CodeFarmer.  I tried to paste in my web.config above but it didn't work out too well.  Anyway, thanks for the info but my web.config has these namespaces.  In fact I temporarily used a default config file from a new project but the problem was still there.  Any idea what else it could be?  thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's a cache problem, try ignore intellisense and error, paste or write it anyway. Then build it see if that's work. I got same problem in the project my colleague create few month ago, i can't find the reason either, so i just ignore it(not using ofen),  now i check it the problem is gone.(ps: maybe relate to code encode type or something, because it' only appear in the project which create by the specific colleague, also you can try delete all file under folder `obj` of this project then rebuild.)

Comment: This worked for me. It was the `"System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0` line. I forgot to change it to version `5.2.7.0` after upgrading System.Web.Mvc. In your case you should have made it `5.2.3.0`. I guess you solved it years ago!

Answer (score 0):

Class containing form-related extensions `FormExtensions` is contained in `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions(v=vs.118).aspx)), not `System.Web.Mvc`. Try adding `System.Web.Mvc.Html` to `Web.config` inside `Views` folder and it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks for this, kiziu.  That's useful to know.  Unfortunately I don't think it's a web.config issue (see my comment above).  Do you have any other ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Demonplus... have you resolved it. I have the same problem.. thanks!!